# mysql yesterday date with specific timestamp

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I am in a situation where i need to query data base to fetch records from yesterday with time stamp, for an example today is 25 so clause should be like:

```
STR_TO_DATE(created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-04-24 23:00:00' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I can get the previous date, but can't set it to 23:00:00 time, any idea's please?

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 DAY)
  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  , HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  , DATE_ADD(
    CURDATE() INTERVAL - ((HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1)) HOUR
  )
```

But it gives an error, i tried to subtract the todays HOURS +1 from current timestamp.

Comment: `curdate() - interval 1 hour`

Comment: @juergend i know that already brother, issue is number of hours are dynamic, subtracting number of hours from current time stamp so that it should give me yesterday date with time "23:00:00"

Comment: That is exactly what this is giving you. Did you try it?

Comment: I need to get the orders which are between yerterdaydate 2:00:00 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Lolz :) you are right, post your answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
curdate() - interval 1 hour
```

Since `curdate()` gives you the current date WITHOUT time. Substract an hour from it and you get yesterday 23:00.